# How do you create a title screen for an android app? E.g. When the app is loading like Facebook

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

Hi I am developing an app and I cannot find how to create title/loading screens when the app boots up? Is it a new activity or a function? Any help is appreciated thanks.

Comment: You mean a splash screen? [Here's](http://cyrilmottier.com/2012/05/03/splash-screens-are-evil-dont-use-them/) an opinion.

Answer (score 1):

You want a [splash](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/how-to-implement-android-splash-screen-2/) screen.  There are a bunch of topics on google about it.

Answer (score 0):

Its actually called a splash screen, it should be something like:

```
class SplashScreen extends Activity{
 /* in oncreate do all the function u want and after that finish this activity*/
public void oncreate(){
 new BackGroundProcess.execute(arguments)// async task to load data
 intent i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this,OtherActivity.class);
 startActivity(i);
 finish();
}
}

class BackGroundProcess extends AsyncTask<arguments>
{
       public onPreExecute(){
         // start your progress dialog here
       }
       public doInBackground(){
          //loadDataHere
       }
       public onPostExecute(){
         // stop your progress dialog here
       }
}
```

for help you can try [this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html) or [this](http://blog.blundell-apps.com/tut-splashscreen-with-progress-bar/)